# Issue while installing a language pack

Tags: language, server

I tried to install a spanish language pack through magento connect. It seems it was already installed since in the magento connect screen I got a message saying something like : "error : this file is already installed". Since then the server is down.

How can I fix this ? I haven't written down the path to the exact file that seems to cause this issue, and I can't find it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by the `maintenance.flag` file. This often happens when installation via Magento Connect Manager cannot be completed.

Use FTP or SSH to look for this file in your Magento root directory. When you find it rename it to `maintenance.flag_bk` or just remove it completely.

After this look through your Magento file system for files of the extension you are trying to install. When you find them just remove them all and after that try and install the language pack again.

Answer (score 0):

in Magento root directory /pub inside you have maintenance.flag file just Remove 
using

$ rm -rf maintenance.flag

$ php bin/magento cache:flush

run this two commands using ssh (terminal/putty)